# Logic to determine a postal carrier based on the tracking number C#

Tags: c#

working on some simple logic to determine a postal carrier based on the tracking number. I am trying to put the tracking number into an array called "trackingNumberArray" then have a few if statements that compare various items of that array to determine the carrier. This is the code I have but still cannot seem to make it work. Any tips/guideance would be greatly appreciated!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string trackingNumber = "1Z204E380338943508";

        string[] trackingNumberArray = new string[] {trackingNumber};


            if (trackingNumberArray.Contains("1Z"))
            {
                string carrierName = "UPS";
                Console.WriteLine($"Carrier Name" + carrierName);
            }
            else if (trackingNumberArray.Length >= 12 && trackingNumberArray.Length < 14 && !!trackingNumberArray.Contains("1Z"))
            {
                string carrierName = "Fedex";
                Console.WriteLine($"Carrier Name" + carrierName);
            }
            else if (trackingNumberArray.Length >= 20 && trackingNumberArray.Length < 22 && !trackingNumberArray.Contains("1Z"))
            {
                string carrierName = "USPS";
                Console.WriteLine($"Carrier Name" + carrierName);
            }
            else
            {
                string carrierName = null;
                Console.WriteLine($"did not work" + carrierName);
            }


    }
```

Comment: You're treating the array as a string. Just use `trackingNumber` and remove the array.

Comment: Would all "fedex" be flagged as "UPS" due to the `!!` operator on fedex `else if`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the tracking number into an array, you can just leave it as a string. The rest of your code should then work with that string. You also don't need the redundant checks for `"1Z"`, since that was in the first conditon:

```
static void Main()
{
    string trackingNumber = "1Z204E380338943508";
    string carrierName = null;

    if (trackingNumber.Contains("1Z"))
    {
        carrierName = "UPS";
    }
    else if (trackingNumber.Length >= 12 && trackingNumber.Length < 14)
    {
        carrierName = "FedEx";
    }
    else if (trackingNumber.Length >= 20 && trackingNumber.Length < 22)
    {
        carrierName = "USPS";
    }

    if (carrierName == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did not work.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Carrier name: {carrierName}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nPress any key to exit...");
}
```

You could then create a `static` method out of the code:

```
public static string GetCarrierName(string trackingNumber)
{
    if (trackingNumber == null) return null;
    if (trackingNumber.Contains("1Z")) return "UPS";
    if (trackingNumber.Length >= 12 && trackingNumber.Length < 14) return "FedEx";
    if (trackingNumber.Length >= 20 && trackingNumber.Length < 22) return "USPS";
    return null;
}
```

And use it like:

```
static void Main()
{
    string carrierName = GetCarrierName("1Z204E380338943508");

    if (carrierName == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown tracking id format.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Carrier name: {carrierName}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nPress any key to exit...");
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Moving the WriteLine to the end was a nice refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

```
trackingNumberArray.Contains("1Z")
```

This won't work because your array is made up of individual letters. If you want to look for a string, use the original string.

```
trackingNumber.Contains("1Z")
```

Also, there's no need for this bit, because it's in an 'else' that can only be reached when it's true.

```
&& !trackingNumberArray.Contains("1Z")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I took your advice and now when I change the tracking number I dont get a result. if you wouldn't mind looking once more at what I have I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: string trackingNumber = "797615467620";

            string carrierName = null;

            if (trackingNumber.Contains("1Z"))
            {
                carrierName = "UPS";
            }
            else if (trackingNumber.Length > 12 && trackingNumber.Length < 14)
            {
                carrierName = "Fedex";
            }
            else if (trackingNumber.Length > 20 && trackingNumber.Length < 22)
            {
                carrierName = "USPS";
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Carrier Name: {carrierName}");
            
        }

Comment: That number is 12 digits long, but you've specified that FedEx numbers need to be greater than 12 characters long. I think you want `>= 12`, not `>12`. Try putting a breakpoint on that line and checking the value of `trackingNumber.Length > 12`